# I have difficulty in understanding the following CSS code

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am trying to understand this code, I was not been able to find any article on the internet and I don't even know what kind of CSS code is this, a detailed explanation with some good example would be appreciated.

```
  .\36 u, .\36 u\24 {
     width: 50%;
     clear: none;
     margin-left: 0;
   }
   .\35 u, .\35 u\24 {
     width: 41.6666666667%;
     clear: none;
     margin-left: 0;
   }
   .\34 u, .\34 u\24 {
     width: 33.3333%;
     clear: none;
     margin-left: 0;
   }
   .proud{
     width:50%;
   }
   .\33 u, .\33 u\24 {
     width: 75%;
     clear: none;
     margin-left: 0;
   }
   .\32 u, .\32 u\24 {
     width: 16.6666666667%;
     clear: none;
     margin-left: 0;
   }
 .\31 u, .\31 u\24 {
    width: 8.3333333333%;
    clear: none;
    margin-left: 0;
   }
```

Comment: what you want to know ?

Comment: can u give the html structure also so that it will be easy to explain

Comment: <div class="row">
                    <div class="12u">
                        <h1><a href="#" class="nov" id="logo">Novel Tutorials</a></h1>
                        <br><h4 class="tagline">Where Teaching is a Religion....!</h4>
                        <div class="head_novel">
                            <h4 class="sec_novel">